# Call to Pythons mutliprocessing.Process.join() fails

Tags: python-3.x, docker, crash, multiprocessing

When I run the code below it occasionally fails

```py
time_start = time.time()
job = multiprocessing.Process(target=load_cpu, args=(deadline, ))
job.start() # This is line 37 in the source code linked below
# timeout=None in the call to join() solves the problem
job.join(deadline)
elapsed = time.time()-time_start
if elapsed < deadline and job.is_alive():
    # I am getting here from time to time
    logger.error(f"#{job_counter}: job.join() returned while process {job.pid} is still alive elapsed={elapsed} deadline={deadline}")
```

The Python 3.7 container (Docker) demonstrating the problem is here https://github.com/larytet-py/multiprocess
If I run the code for a few minutes on a 4 cores Ubuntu 18.04 host I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 37, in spawn_job
    job.start()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 111, in start
    _cleanup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/process.py", line 56, in _cleanup
    if p._popen.poll() is not None:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'poll'
```

What am I doing wrong? 
My workaround is to replace the call to job.join() with a polling and check is_alive(). Unfortunately this approach impacts latency. Are there better alternatives?

```
def join_process(job, timeout):
    time_start = time.time()
    # Typical processing time is 100ms I want to reduce latency impact
    # 10ms looks ok. 
    # TODO I can end up in a tight loop here. 
    polling_time = min(0.1*timeout, 0.010)
    while time.time()-time_start < timeout and job.is_alive():
        time.sleep(polling_time)
        continue
```

Update. I tried multiprocessing.Event() instead of Process.join() The code fails with the same exception

Update2. I have reproduced the problem in the code not calling Process.join() at all. It require more time and more load, but eventually Process.start() crashes.

Update3. https://bugs.python.org/issue40860 is accepted? I am still looking for a workaround.

Comment: Can you please post the full traceback?

Comment: Are you possibly running your code on a mac or windows machine?

Comment: @Hannu The host is Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I have updated the trace

Comment: It seems your job already fails at ``job.start()``. Are you sure that using ``job.join()`` with ``timeout=None`` fixes the problem, or is this just coincidental?

Comment: This is a curious problem. When running on a mac I can reproduce your issue. And by adding some more debugging, it seems that all subprocesses complete in 0.04 seconds or so but some of them take significantly longer to return from .join().  Macs use "spawn" method to create subprocesses. When I changed that to "fork", everything works absolutely fine and subprocesses terminate immediately after the worker completes and no join timeouts occur.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you put `multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")`  as the first line in your __main__, will it change things for the better for you as well?

Comment: As a general observation, your program creates a lot of overhead in creating and shutting down subprocesses. If you are interested in performance and latency, this would be a prime candidate for `multiprocessing.Pool()` where a fixed amount of worker subprocesses are created once and reused to execute tasks. In cases like this the performance increase can be significant.  This gets rid of the process management overhead.

Comment: @Hannu This patch did not help ```
+    multiprocessing.set_start_method("fork")
```  I think Python in Linux uses fork

Comment: My goal is to have a deadline for process execution. Typical processing time is ~200ms, the deadline is 30s. About 0.5% of all cases do require close to or above 30s.

Comment: Back to testing then. Just ran your code on ubuntu without docker, works absolutely fine.

Comment: I have Python 3.6 on the host, I am getting ```returned while process 29867 is still alive elapsed=0.042801618576049805 deadline=0.2```  How join(0.2) returns before the timeout and the process is still alive?  A bug in the Docker kernel driver is quite probable.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This is a very good question, In my real application I had to drop all calls to join() because of the failures in the multiprocessing communication pipe. Update. I tried it again. The code does not crash, but join(None) occasionally returns while call job.is_alive() still returns True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronizing the call to Process.start() helps. This is a fair workaround. There no other answers. I am accepting my own answer.

```
diff --git a/main.py b/main.py
index d09dc53..49d68f0 100644
--- a/main.py
+++ b/main.py
@@ -26,17 +26,24 @@ def load_cpu(deadline):
     while time.time() - start < 0.2*deadline:
         math.pow(random.randint(0, 1), random.randint(0, 1))
 
+def join_process(job, timeout):
+    time_start = time.time()
+    while time.time()-time_start < timeout and job.is_alive():
+        time.sleep(0.1   * timeout)
+        continue
+
 job_counter = 0
+lock = threading.Lock()
 def spawn_job(deadline):
     '''
     Creat a new Process, call join(), process errors
     '''    
     global job_counter
     time_start = time.time()
-    job = multiprocessing.Process(target=load_cpu, args=(deadline, ))
-    job.start()
-    # timeout=None in the call to join() solves the problem
-    job.join(deadline)
+    with lock:
+        job = multiprocessing.Process(target=load_cpu, args=(deadline, ))
+        job.start()
+    join_process(job, deadline)
```

My final version uses os.fork(). I drop multiprocessing altogether. The multiprocessing is not thread safe (I am kidding not) https://gist.github.com/larytet/3ca9f9a32b1dc089a24cb7011455141f

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/104536 process is not thread safe...